# Is there any iPad-compatible keyboard that is arbitrarily remappable?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados, accessories, magic-keyboard-ipad

I'm looking for a keyboard model that would be able to connect to my iPad and be possible to reprogram at the accessory-level to have custom key mappings/layouts. I understand that many mechanical keyboard are programmable in this way, and I've seen several that appear to be compatible with iPad, however I'm not sure if any of them are actually reprogrammable.

Otherwise is anyone aware of any iPad keyboards with "hackable" or jailbroken firmware?

Comment: Any arbitrary alternative layout... Why do you ask?

Comment: No I'm more interested in exploring alternative keyboard layouts for typing prose such as Dvorak or Colemak

Comment: Apple already provides iOS hardware  layouts like that, at least for the English keyboard setting, specifically Dvorak, Dvorak Qwerty CMD, Dvorak Left Handed, Dvorak Right Handed, and Colemak.  So you would not need anything extra to do those.

Comment: Okay, I'm actually interested in experimenting and possibly creating my own customisations of those, so I would actually still like to find a solution.

Comment: I'm interested in this too for halmak - which macos bundle doesn't work well (seems increasingly unsupported by Apple), so looking for a hardware remap keyboard like Launch by System76 however that doesn't have bluetooth for iPad compatibility - that said, I could workaround this by mission control or whatever it is (using the m1 mac mini's peripherals with the ipad nearby as a connected device).